# Tsung crashes with ** Reason for termination == ** {{badmatch,false}

Tags: performance, http, tsung

I am using tsung ,compiled with openssl and erlang for sending queries.

In the tsung_controller.log I am getting this error :

```
** Reason for termination ==

    ** {{badmatch,false},
        [{ts_config_server,handle_call,3,
                           [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_config_server.erl"},
                            {line,305}]},
         {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,628}]},
         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,660}]},
         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,238}]}]}
```

And:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Aug-2015::01:07:42 ===
** Generic server ts_config_server terminating
** Last message in was {get_client_config,static,"*****commented this **"}
** When Server state == {state,
                         {config,undefined,1200,5,none,text,undefined,
```

I have verified that the setup using the information from user manual 
http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/faq.html and getting OK.

so setup looks fine to me .But I am not able to figure out the exact reason for crash.

At some forum I have seen the answer that the query file mentioned in the .xml file could be the reason.But I have tried with absolute and relative path ,unfortunately it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this message from 10 years ago in their mailing list](http://lists.process-one.net/pipermail/tsung-users/2005-November/000168.html)

and my experience today, you are probably using a Fully Qualified Host Name instead of a short hostname .e.g. **"mymachine.domain.tld"** instead of **"mymachine"** as a value for the host attribute in the client tag, as the documentation points on in item [10.1](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/faq.html#can-t-start-distributed-clients-timeout-error)